# How to build Android spatialite?

Tags: spatialite, android, sqlite

I have been trying to build spatialite for Android for a few days now without success. I have even tried the recent documentation from the Google project page here: https://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/. Build documentation is is quite vague and there are not many resources on the interweb to help me out. Just wondering if this project has seen adoption or is simply dead. If its dead its too bad... it was a good initiative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this Spatialite web page that has instructions, source code and binaries for Android?  
 https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android
Also, the "SpatiaLite Users" google group might be helpful.

Comment: The building was working it was simply me expecting a different library name. From reading the instructions in the tutorial I thought the output was libspatialite.so but its actually libjsqlite.so. All good and working great.